# Spark Scala Dataframe Sequence of JSON from a CSV file

Tags: json, scala, csv, apache-spark, sequence

I have a field in a CSV file which contains a sequence of JSON.  See below for mock data.  from_json only recognizes sequences of 1 item.  Could someone provide guidance on the Spark/Scala idiomatic way of converting the string field to a sequence?  I believe once I have a sequence, I can explode the field and use the from_json function.

```
|MainId|genres                                                                                                                       |
+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|862   |[{'id': 16, 'name': 'Animation'}, {'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}, {'id': 10751, 'name': 'Family'}]                             |
|8844  |[{'id': 12, 'name': 'Adventure'}, {'id': 14, 'name': 'Fantasy'}, {'id': 10751, 'name': 'Family'}]                            |
|15602 |[{'id': 10749, 'name': 'Romance'}, {'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}]                                                             |
|31357 |[{'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}, {'id': 18, 'name': 'Drama'}, {'id': 10749, 'name': 'Romance'}]                                |
|11862 |[{'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}]
```

Comment: You can use spark to read this column as a json: val jsonDF = spark.read.json(df("genres")) if you need the MainId, you can use monotonically_increasing_id first and then join your dataframes

Comment: Unfortunately that construction doesn't work.  I'm using Spark 2.4 if that is helpful.

Comment: Could you please share the schema for the `df`?

Comment: Here is the schema for the input dataframe

Comment: ```
 adult: boolean 
  belongs_to_collection: string 
 budget: integer 
 genres: string
 homepage: string 
 MainId: string
 imdb_id: string 
 original_language: string
 original_title: string
 overview: string 
 popularity: double
 poster_path: string 
 production_companies: string
 production_countries: string
 release_date: date
 revenue: integer
 runtime: double
 spoken_language: string
 status: string
 tagline: string 
 title: string 
 video: boolean 
 vote_average: double 
 vote_count: integer 
```

Comment: Why aren't the carriage returns preserved?  Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
scala> df.show(false)
+------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|MainId|genres                                                                                |
+------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|862   |[{'id':16,'name':'Animation'},{'id':35,'name':'Comedy'},{'id':10751,'name':'Family'}] |
|8844  |[{'id':12,'name':'Adventure'},{'id':14,'name':'Fantasy'},{'id':10751,'name':'Family'}]|
|15602 |[{'id':10749,'name':'Romance'},{'id':35,'name':'Comedy'}]                             |
|31357 |[{'id':35,'name':'Comedy'},{'id':18,'name':'Drama'},{'id':10749,'name':'Romance'}]    |
|11862 |[{'id':35,'name':'Comedy'}]                                                           |
+------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+


scala> val df1 = df.withColumn("genres", regexp_replace(col("genres"), "[\\[\\]{}']", ""))
                   .withColumn("genres", explode(split(col("genres"), ",")))
                   .withColumn("columns", split(col("genres"), ":")(0))
                   .withColumn("value", split(col("genres"), ":")(1))

scala> df1.show(false)
+------+--------------+-------+---------+
|MainId|genres        |columns|value    |
+------+--------------+-------+---------+
|862   |id:16         |id     |16       |
|862   |name:Animation|name   |Animation|
|862   |id:35         |id     |35       |
|862   |name:Comedy   |name   |Comedy   |
|862   |id:10751      |id     |10751    |
|862   |name:Family   |name   |Family   |
|8844  |id:12         |id     |12       |
|8844  |name:Adventure|name   |Adventure|
|8844  |id:14         |id     |14       |
|8844  |name:Fantasy  |name   |Fantasy  |
|8844  |id:10751      |id     |10751    |
|8844  |name:Family   |name   |Family   |
|15602 |id:10749      |id     |10749    |
|15602 |name:Romance  |name   |Romance  |
|15602 |id:35         |id     |35       |
|15602 |name:Comedy   |name   |Comedy   |
|31357 |id:35         |id     |35       |
|31357 |name:Comedy   |name   |Comedy   |
|31357 |id:18         |id     |18       |
|31357 |name:Drama    |name   |Drama    |
+------+--------------+-------+---------+

scala>  val df2 = df1.groupBy("MainId").pivot("columns")
                     .agg(collect_list(col("value")))
                     .withColumn("json", explode(arrays_zip(col("id"), col("name"))))
                     .select("MainId", "json")

scala> df2.show()
+------+----------------+
|MainId|            json|
+------+----------------+
|   862| [16, Animation]|
|   862|    [35, Comedy]|
|   862| [10751, Family]|
| 15602|[10749, Romance]|
| 15602|    [35, Comedy]|
| 11862|    [35, Comedy]|
| 31357|    [35, Comedy]|
| 31357|     [18, Drama]|
| 31357|[10749, Romance]|
|  8844| [12, Adventure]|
|  8844|   [14, Fantasy]|
|  8844| [10751, Family]|
+------+----------------+


scala> df2.select("MainId","json.id","json.name").show
+------+-----+---------+
|MainId|   id|     name|
+------+-----+---------+
|   862|   16|Animation|
|   862|   35|   Comedy|
|   862|10751|   Family|
| 15602|10749|  Romance|
| 15602|   35|   Comedy|
| 11862|   35|   Comedy|
| 31357|   35|   Comedy|
| 31357|   18|    Drama|
| 31357|10749|  Romance|
|  8844|   12|Adventure|
|  8844|   14|  Fantasy|
|  8844|10751|   Family|
+------+-----+---------+
```